# How do I make predictions with a trained neural network that uses text vectorization?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm building an autoencoder neural network to analyze logs and detect anomalies in .csv logs that contain text and numerical data. I've managed to complete the training and save the finished model. Now according to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#using_tfdata , when I save the model the preprocessing layer is saved with it, in my understanding that means I can pass it the raw new logs I aim to analyze, which will be processed just as the training logs: text vectorization first, then passed on to network. However I get the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 972) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 972), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1).

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model_1" (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 972, but received input with shape (None, 1)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=string)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

This is the code I use for the training:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

columnsToUse = [
    "_source.log.OriginalTimestamp",
    "_source.log.SenderID",
    "_source.host.ip",
    "_source.log.Severity",
    "_source.log.message_text",
    "_source.host.mac",
    "_source.log.offset",
]

df = pd.read_csv("log.csv", usecols=columnsToUse)
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).dropna()


log_features = df.copy()

inputs = {}

for name, column in log_features.items():
    dtype = column.dtype
    if dtype == object:
        dtype = tf.string
    else:
        dtype = tf.float32

    inputs[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=name, dtype=dtype)

numeric_inputs = {
    name: input for name, input in inputs.items() if input.dtype == tf.float32
}

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(list(numeric_inputs.values()))
norm = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
norm.adapt(np.array(df[numeric_inputs.keys()]))
all_numeric_inputs = norm(x)


preprocessed_inputs = [all_numeric_inputs]


for name, input in inputs.items():
    if input.dtype == tf.float32:
        continue

    lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=np.unique(log_features[name]))
    one_hot = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=lookup.vocabulary_size())

    x = lookup(input)
    x = one_hot(x)
    preprocessed_inputs.append(x)


preprocessed_inputs_cat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(preprocessed_inputs)

log_preprocessing = tf.keras.Model(inputs, preprocessed_inputs_cat)


tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model=log_preprocessing,
    to_file="preprocessing.png",
    rankdir="LR",
    dpi=72,
    show_shapes=True,
)


log_features_dict = {name: np.array(value) for name, value in log_features.items()}


features_dict = {name: values[:1] for name, values in log_features_dict.items()}
print(log_preprocessing(features_dict))

processed_features = log_preprocessing(log_features_dict)
features_len = log_preprocessing.output_shape[-1]


def log_model():
    input_layer = Input((features_len))
    layer = Dense(7)(input_layer)
    layer = Dense(5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(7)(layer)
    output_layer = Dense(features_len)(layer)

    model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE,
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
        metrics=tf.keras.metrics.MSE
    )

    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
        model=model,
        to_file="model.png",
        rankdir="LR",
        dpi=72,
        show_shapes=True,
    )

    return model


final_model = log_model()
final_model.fit(x=processed_features, y=processed_features, epochs=30)

final_model.save('autoencoder')
```

And after reloading it, I try the following code which gives me the error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('autoencoder7557')

df = pd.read_csv("testlog.csv")

predictions = model.predict(df)
```

I've uploaded the training log and the test log here: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/09avGmR28qGmADe7obvmv7byA#log

I've tried loading the training dataset for the testing as well, and that also gave the same error.